# Video API integration for create online meeting in website using php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, video-streaming, scheduler

Need some suggestions about video API integration
this is not a open source. we need to create account on vidyo.com and they will provide account for accessing sample codes.

Did any one know about video API or experience with this API.

I need to integrate in my client website for create a meeting with AUDIO/VIDEO chat, also record as well.

Meeting will create with in particular users.

So please any one guide me or give the solution for this scenario for best API.

thanks.

Comment: Just built a custom telehealth solution using Vidyo (medisprout.com).  Vidyo is very customizable and stable.  The API integration was difficult but only because we developed custom web, ios, and android clients.  We also communicate with the VidyoPortal via the API.  Vidyo requires server infrastructure.  You can buy your own Vidyo servers or use a service provider.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register with Vidyo. Then you will get access API support. You will get API sample and libraries from [Vidyo](http://www.developer.vidyo.com). Once you get that access, you can easily integrate Vidyo conferencing in your custom web based application.

Chat, recording facility is there. You can not get chat history from Vidyo API. You have to save chat history manually into your system.

Vidyo is high quality system which requires high network bandwidth also high cost. If you want low cost conference system, you can go for WebRTC system.

Answer (score 0):

Vidyo is working great, but when I started looking for Video conferencing solutions, there are few other providers I came through,

1. Bluejeans
2. Zoom.us
3. Trueconf

which also uses the H.264 Scalable Video Codec(SVC) technology.